# Solve $\left( 3x^{2}y\right) \frac{dy}{dx} =x^{3}+y^{3}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve this differential equation$$ \left( 3x^{2}y\right) \frac{dy}{dx} =x^{3}+y^{3}$$
My trial is 
I divided both sides with $3x^{2}y $ then I get 
$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{1}{3} \left[ \left( \frac{x}{y} \right) +\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) ^{2}\right] $
And then I made $\frac{y}{x} = z $ 
And after differentiation I get 
$$ \int \frac{1}{3x} dx=\int \frac{1}{\frac{1}{z} +z^{2}-3z} dz$$ the integration W. R. T $x $ is easy But for $z $ make me stop here... how I can complete to the full solution of this differential equation ?

Comment: Try substituting $z = \frac{x}{y}$ instead.

Comment: @JoeyZou. Do you think that it makes the problem simpler ? I tried and arrived to the same kind of problems.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Using your approach 
$$\int \frac{dz}{\frac{1}{z} +z^{2}-3z} =\int \frac{z}{z^{3}-3z^2+1} dz$$ The denominator has three real roots (you could prove it using Cardano formula) which have ugly numerical expressions (their numerical values are $\approx 2.87939, -0.532089, 0.652704$). So, let us name them $a,b,c$.

Now, using partial fraction decomposition $$\frac z{(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)}=\frac{A}{ (z-a)}+\frac{B}{(z-b)}+\frac{C}{(z-c)}$$ where $$A=\frac{a}{(a-b) (a-c)}\quad B=\frac{b}{(b-a) (b-c)}\quad C=\frac{c}{(c-a) (c-b)}$$

So, the integral in  the rhs is a linear combination of logarithms $$\int \frac{dz}{\frac{1}{z} +z^{2}-3z} =A \,\log(z-a)+B\, \log(z-b)+C\, \log(z-c)$$ with $A\approx 0.379053, B \approx -0.131644, C \approx -0.247409$.